# Rating algorithm for android/mysql

Tags: android, mysql

Im a dummy in android development and currently creating an android application and trying to implement a rating system, allowing a user to submit a review and be rated by other users. I would like to know how the whole process is going to be like and what algorithm will be needed.

A guidance will be greatly apperciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: What about averaging votes and rounding to the nearest unit that makes sense (e.g. "half-star")? You could keep an average, the number of votes, and for each new vote, add the (newvote-average)/(votecount+1) to the previous average value. See [that page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Cumulative_moving_average) for instance.

Comment: Yes i will be needing the average rating to allow user to see the total average vote rated by others. What would be the sql syntax like for rounding up the total rating?

Answer (score 3):

If you are open to other websites that creates rating systems I am sure there are tons that you can find online

Comment: I believe there is to a certain extend but very limited and they are not clear cut, which requires much experience in android development and i have stated I am new to android development. Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

[This example](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/overheard.html) shows a voting algorithm for Google App Engine (a possible server platform for your Android app).

Comment: Thanks for the example, but will i be able to use this to link with Android Widget RatingBar because i would like to have user to use the RatingBar to rate. Thanks

Comment: Example is not there anymore :/